# Detect shutdown event with python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, shutdown

I have a Minecraft bedrock edition server running on our shared pc. I would like to interface with it via python. However, one problem I have is that my brothers sometimes restart our pc, or Windows updates. I need to know how to detect that shutdown event and send the shutdown command to the server before restart. I am using the subprocess library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you will need is the win32API and the function described [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__SetConsoleCtrlHandler_meth.html). You can use this function to add what's called a Control Handler Method that will run whenever the program is being shut down or terminated for any reason, including shutdown. You can find a list of the different codes that can be passed to the handler and their meanings [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine). Ideally, you should have a handler method that just shuts down the server, waits for it to finish shutting down, and then return.

I don't have any personal experience with the library, but it should be fairly straightforward.

EDIT: as noted by @ErykSun, you will need to create a hidden window in order to receive the events. To be quite honest I'm not sure how to create that hidden window. Some documentation suggests that running your application as a service may also work. I will look into this more if I get time.

Comment: python.exe loads user32.dll. So even as just a console app, the system sees it as a GUI app and does not send control events for logoff and shutdown events. As suggested in the last two paragraphs in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler#remarks) for `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`, the script will have to create a hidden window and handle `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` and `WM_ENDSESSION`.

Comment: @ErykSun Thanks, you are absolutely right. I will add that to my answer.