# Python how to save an txt file in case of sudden pc shutdown?

Tags: python, file, save, shutdown, txt

I'm working on a small visual project which will be generated by my mouse movement throughout the days.

To accomplish this I'm logging my mouse data from my pc fairly rapidly (maybe up to 20 logs/sec).

I'm simply appending my data to a `.txt` one line at a time.


Currently, I use the following method to append to my data file:

```
import time

file_object = open('./logs/test.txt', 'a+', encoding="utf-8")

while True:
    file_object.write(f"{time.time()}\n")
    time.sleep(1)

file_object.close()
```

In this scenario, I know the `file_object` is not gonna close and save, which is my point.

If my script is not exited correctly like if I were to turn my pc off, or I run out of power.

The log will not be saved and I've lost all my data.


I know the `with` way of appending to a document should save on hard shutdowns, but I use a lot of functions and other `with` statements from where I append to the `.txt` file, and I see no way how I could implement it.


In other words, I'm really looking for a way to detect hard shutdowns and call `file_object.close()` to save the document before the computer dies out.

Or of course other smart alternatives.


Enlighten me :)

Thanks for the help

Comment: `file_object.flush()` should ensure all pending output is actually written to the file.

Comment: Why not use a module like [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) that takes care of all this for you?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://danielkaes.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/how-to-catch-kill-events-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

Id simply close and reopen the file on every log entry. It should be able to handle 3 logs/sec.

```
import time

while True:
    file_object = open('./logs/test.txt', 'a+', encoding="utf-8")
    file_object.write(f"{time.time()}\n")
    file_object.close()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You're right thanks for your answer. Sadly 3 logs/sec is way lower than reality. Sorry I have no idea how it ended up there. My bad

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you can use Win32Api function. Better described on this:

[Detect shutdown event with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856197/detect-shutdown-event-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

you can alse use this

import time

while True:

```
with open('./logs/test.txt', 'a+', encoding="utf-8") as file_object:

    file_object.write(f"{time.time()}\n")

    time.sleep(1)
```